# Total derivatives and inverse

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $\zeta: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a $C^1$ function that is total differentiable with $\zeta (0,0) = (0,0)$ and where $(d\zeta)(0,0)$ is invertible. Write $\zeta_1$ as the first component function.

Show that for any function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ it holds that if $f \circ \zeta_1$ is total differentiable in $(0,0)$ then $f$ is differentiable in $0$.

This was part of an exam for an introductory course of real analysis. I wasn't able to find the solution in time, but I haven't had time to revisit the problem until now.

Comment: Should I add what we use as definitions for total differentiability etc?